Unable to Login to AXIGEN CLI via Telnet
I am unable to get the  prompt while logging into AXIGEN CLI via telnet.
It only reads the prompt till  and once the username is entered, it does not read the next Prompt that is 
This is my code:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Request, Query
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi
from pydantic import BaseModel
import telnetlib
from typing import List, Tuple, Union

app = FastAPI()

class TelnetRequest(BaseModel):
    host: str
    port: int
    username: str
    password: str

@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    """
    Root endpoint that returns a simple message.

    This endpoint is documented using docstrings.
    """
    return {"message": "Hello, World"}


def read_until_prompt(tn: telnetlib.Telnet, prompts: Union[str, List[str]], timeout: int = 10) -> bool:
    try:
        if isinstance(prompts, str):
            prompts = [prompts]
        while True:
            output = tn.read_very_eager().decode('ascii')
            for prompt in prompts:
                if prompt in output:
                    return True
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Error while reading prompt: " + str(e))


def send_command(tn: telnetlib.Telnet, command: str) -> bool:
    try:
        tn.write(command.encode('ascii') + b'\n')
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Error while sending command: " + str(e))
        return False

@app.post("/telnet/")
async def telnet_command(request: TelnetRequest):
    try:
        host = request.host
        port = request.port
        username = request.username
        password = request.password

        if not all([host, port, username, password]):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Missing required parameters")

        with telnetlib.Telnet(host, port) as tn:
            if not read_until_prompt(tn, "<login>"):
                raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Login prompt not found")

            send_success = send_command(tn, f"user {username}")
            if not send_success:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Failed to send username command")
                
            if not read_until_prompt(tn, "<password> "):
                raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Password prompt not found")

            send_success = send_command(tn, password)
            if not send_success:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Failed to send password command")

            if not read_until_prompt(tn, ["<#>", "<error>", "<invalid>", "<failed>", '+OK']):
                raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Login failed")

            if not read_until_prompt(tn, "+OK"):
                raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Command execution failed")

        return {"message": "Command has been sent successfully"}

    except HTTPException as e:
        raise e
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))


def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema
    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title="Telnet API",
        version="0.1.0",
        description="This is a Telnet API",
        routes=app.routes,
    )
    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema
    return app.openapi_schema

app.openapi = custom_openapi

I am expecting it to read the  prompt so that I can login to AXIGEN CLI successfully and have access to it.
